# JQuery UI Datepicker not looking at all days in beforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use beforeShowDay in JQuery Datepicker however it's not looping through all the days.

Here is my code:

```
 function calendarPrep(date) {
      console.log(date);
    }


    $( ".start-datepicker" ).datepicker({
      beforeShowDay : calendarPrep,
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      minDate: new Date(2015, 08, 20),
      maxDate: new Date(2016, 11, 31)
    });
```

This is the output I am getting:
[image]

It is stopping on the 3rd October 2015. Why is this happening?

Comment: DatePicker loads only the nearest weeks from today (Sept 18)... Hit the left/right buttons and you will see more output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay):

> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

So the function will be called only for the days to be displayed.

Comment: Yup, me being a muppet.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeShowDay` is calling `calendarPrep` with every date that is shown on screen. Your calendar, by default, is showing the current month, and on screen it is between `aug 30` to `Oct 3`. The behaviour is the expected.